# django-multilingual and switching between languages on template side

Tags: python, linux, django, multiple-languages

I have changed my language on GeoNode. 
I translated all of the word on that. but actually it doesn't change on the web.
I have done the correct way for changing such as bellow:
copy these files (djangojs.po and django.po) in this direction:
geonode\locale\fa\LC_MESSAGES.
please guide me.
Thanks a lot

Comment: I found the way to solve this problem. Finally by helping mr.almalki we could do that. You should copy django-admin.py in geonode directory beside setting.py and so do compile that.

Answer (score 1):

After adding the translation file, you need to compile it:

```
django-admin compilemessages
```

To do so, you will also need gettext tools to be installed in your system.

All of this is documented in [django docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#compiling-message-files)

Comment: I did that but I use of osgeo live an it doesn't work in it's terminal.

Comment: In addition to I have been using of linux as platfom